# How to fit a rotated and translated hyperbola to a set of x,y points in Python

Tags: python, least-squares, data-fitting, svd, eigenvector

I want to fit a set of data points in the xy plane to the general case of a rotated and translated hyperbola to back out the coefficients of the general equation of a conic.
I've tried the methodology proposed in [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220049967_Direct_and_specific_least-square_fitting_of_hyperbol_and_ellipses) but so far I cannot make it work.
When fitting to a set of points known to be a hyperbola I get quite different outputs.
What I'm doing wrong in the code below?
Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import plot_implicit, Eq
from sympy.abc import x, y

def fit_hyperbola(x, y):   
    D1 = np.vstack([x**2, x*y, y**2]).T
    D2 = np.vstack([x, y, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    S1 = D1.T @ D1
    S2 = D1.T @ D2
    S3 = D2.T @ D2

    # define the constraint matrix and its inverse
    C = np.array(((0, 0, -2), (0, 1, 0), (-2, 0, 0)), dtype=float)
    Ci = np.linalg.inv(C)

    # Setup and solve the generalized eigenvector problem
    T = np.linalg.inv(S3) @ S2.T

    S = Ci@(S1 - S2@T)

    eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(S)

    # evaluate and sort resulting constraint values
    cond = eigvec[1]**2 - 4*eigvec[0]*eigvec[2]

    # [condVals index] = sort(cond)
    idx = np.argsort(cond)
    condVals = cond[idx]

    possibleHs = condVals[1:] + condVals[0]
    minDiffAt = np.argmin(abs(possibleHs))
    # minDiffVal = possibleHs[minDiffAt]
    alpha1 = eigvec[:, idx[minDiffAt + 1]]
    alpha2 = T@alpha1
    return np.concatenate((alpha1, alpha2)).ravel()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # known hyperbola coefficients
    coeffs = [1., 6., -2., 3., 0., 0.]

    # hyperbola points
    x_ = [1.56011303e+00, 1.38439984e+00, 1.22595618e+00, 1.08313085e+00,
           9.54435408e-01, 8.38528681e-01, 7.34202759e-01, 6.40370424e-01,
           5.56053814e-01, 4.80374235e-01, 4.12543002e-01, 3.51853222e-01,
           2.97672424e-01, 2.49435970e-01, 2.06641170e-01, 1.68842044e-01,
           1.35644673e-01, 1.06703097e-01, 8.17157025e-02, 6.04220884e-02,
           4.26003457e-02, 2.80647476e-02, 1.66638132e-02, 8.27872926e-03,
           2.82211172e-03, 2.37095181e-04, 4.96740239e-04, 3.60375275e-03,
           9.59051203e-03, 1.85194083e-02, 3.04834928e-02, 4.56074477e-02,
           6.40488853e-02, 8.59999904e-02, 1.11689524e-01, 1.41385205e-01,
           1.75396504e-01, 2.14077865e-01, 2.57832401e-01, 3.07116093e-01,
           3.62442545e-01, 4.24388335e-01, 4.93599021e-01, 5.70795874e-01,
           6.56783391e-01, 7.52457678e-01, 8.58815793e-01, 9.76966133e-01,
           1.10813998e+00, 1.25370436e+00]

    y_ =  [-0.66541515, -0.6339625 , -0.60485332, -0.57778425, -0.5524732 ,
           -0.52865638, -0.50608561, -0.48452564, -0.46375182, -0.44354763,
           -0.42370253, -0.4040097 , -0.38426392, -0.3642594 , -0.34378769,
           -0.32263542, -0.30058217, -0.27739811, -0.25284163, -0.22665682,
           -0.19857079, -0.16829086, -0.13550147, -0.0998609 , -0.06099773,
           -0.01850695,  0.02805425,  0.07917109,  0.13537629,  0.19725559,
            0.26545384,  0.34068177,  0.42372336,  0.51544401,  0.61679957,
            0.72884632,  0.85275192,  0.98980766,  1.14144182,  1.30923466,
            1.49493479,  1.70047747,  1.92800474,  2.17988774,  2.45875143,
            2.76750196,  3.10935692,  3.48787892,  3.90701266,  4.3711261 ]


    plot_implicit (Eq(coeffs[0]*x**2 + coeffs[1]*x*y + coeffs[2]*y**2 + coeffs[3]*x + coeffs[4]*y, -coeffs[5]))

    coeffs_fit = fit_hyperbola(x_, y_)

    plot_implicit (Eq(coeffs_fit[0]*x**2 + coeffs_fit[1]*x*y + coeffs_fit[2]*y**2 + coeffs_fit[3]*x + coeffs_fit[4]*y, -coeffs_fit[5]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The general equation of hyperbola is defined with 5 independent coefficients (not 6). If the model equation includes dependant coefficients (which is the case with 6 coefficients) trouble might occur in the numerical regression calculus.

That is why the equation A * x * x + B * x * y + C * y * y + D * x + F * y = 1 is considered in the calculus below. The fitting is very good.

Then one can goback to the standard equation a * x * x + 2 * b * x * y + c * y * y + 2 * d * x + 2 * f * y + g = 0 in setting a value for g (for example g=-1).

The formulas to find the coordinates of the center, the equations of asymptotes, the equations of axis, are given in addition.

[image]

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Comment: I was wondering: if x and y had errors, what error would be minimized? It's probably not the orthogonal distance.

Comment: No, it's not the orthogonal distance. It is the LMSE wrt the hyperbola equation.

Comment: I'm getting mixed results, for some coefficients sets I get quite unstable fits which I suspect is due to the square matrix having the determinant close to zero. This happens with the set in my question and with [2, 5, 1, -3, 0, 0], [1, 5, 1, 0, -4, 0] too for instance. Also, I guess related to the comment above, would this work with "noisy" data?

Comment: @JJacquelin. Sorry for being provocative...and a bit lazy; I am aware of the LMSE, but not sure about the specific geometrical meaning (fiddling a bit with `x->x + dx` etc.) and the effect on the result of x-errors vs y-errors vs xy-errors.

Comment: @AleVis First thing to try is not using the inverse explicitly. Have a look at [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)

Comment: @mikuszefski yes I'm using solve in my implementation. For the coeff sets (of the general equation) in my question and comments I get either a good or a bad fit, randomly. In those cases the determinant of the matrix is essentially zero. For other curves the fit is good and stable. On noisy data (e.g. a hyperbola + random noise) the fit isn't good.

Comment: @AleVis Right, got it. In that case you might use the results from here as a starting point for a non-linear fit. I'd probably try orthogonal distance on a parametric curve `( a cosh(t), b sinh(t) )`